# Загрузка одной страницы много раз

Tags: ajax

При быстром многократном нажатии загружается одна страница много раз:

Скрипт асинхронной загрузки

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
        $(this).text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page' : current_page
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl, // обработчик
            data:data, // данные
            type:'POST', // тип запроса
            success:function(data){
                if( data ) { 
                    $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
                    current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                    if (currentPage == maxPages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
                } else {
                    $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Как в самом начале AJAX-запроса добавлять класс (к body или к кнопке), после выполнения запроса удалить его?

То есть перед нажатием кнопки проверить наличие класса. Если класс есть (т.е. предыдущий запрос не выполнен до конца), то ничего не делаем и насколько это правильный подход ?

Comment: А почему может не работать if (currentPage == maxPages) $el.remove(); ? после первого нажатия загружаются записи, а потом только остается кнопка "Загружается...".

Comment: @rodion Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйте `disabled` для submit-кнопки, что пользователь не мог нажать на неё пока запрос не завершится.

**html:**

```
<div id="true_loadmore">OK</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    
    $el.prop("disabled", true);    
    /*
        jQuery (< 1.7):        
        $el.attr('disabled', true);                
    */
    $el.text('Загружаю...');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/', 
        type: 'POST',      
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){     
            $el.text('Загрузить ещё');
        }           
    })
    .always(function() {
        /*
            jQuery (< 1.7):        
            $el.attr('disabled', false);
        */
        $el.prop("disabled", false);
    });   
});
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/kt9azthk/2/)

**P.S.** В целях оптимизации, кэшируйте элемент в переменную `$el`.

#### UPDATE #1

Вариант с preloader:

**html:**

```
<div id="true_loadmore">Загрузить ещё</div>
<div class="preloader">Загружается...</div>
```

**css:**

```
.preloader {
    display: none;
}
```

**js:**

```
$('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
    var $el = $(this),
        $preloader = $('.preloader');    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/', 
        type: 'POST',      
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function( ) {
            $el.hide(); 
            $preloader.show();
        },
        success: function(data){     
        }           
    })
    .complete(function() {
        $preloader.hide();
        $el.show();           
    });   
});
```

[Смотрите](http://jsfiddle.net/kt9azthk/4/)

#### UPDATE #2

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/', 
    type: 'POST',      
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function( ) {
        $el.hide(); 
        $preloader.show();
    },
    success: function(data){             
        if(!data) {  
            return;
        }
        current_page++; 
        if (currentPage == maxPages) {
            return;
        }                    
        $el.show().before(data);                                
    }           
})
.complete(function() {
    $preloader.hide();          
});
```

Comment: @romio, у меня не совсем кнопка <div id="true_loadmore">Загрузить ещё</div>

Comment: @rodion Исправил ответ

Если четно, никогда не применял `disabled` к элементам, которые не являются контролами/элементами формы. [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423812/enable-disable-a-div-and-its-elements-in-javascript) подсказывает, что можно.

Сделайте button-ом в конце концов.

> То есть перед нажатием кнопки проверить наличие класса...

Как-то костыльно выглядит. Вариант с button-ом проще.

Comment: @romio я добавил http://ssmaker.ru/278d0c3b.png и вообще перестал работать.
p.s. cms wordpress

Comment: @rodion У Вас версия JQuery какая? 

Смотрите в комментарии к коду. Если < 1.7, то вместо `$el.prop` используйте `$el.attr`. Если < 1.6, то вместо `.always(function() {})` используйте `.complete(function() {})`.

Вот [вариант для 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/kt9azthk/3/)

Comment: @romeo JQuery 1.7 еще не пойму, что изменить/добавить нужно изменить здесь http://ssmaker.ru/df659a35.png

Comment: @rodion Добавил вариант с preloader

Comment: @romeo огромнейшее спасибо, все очень хорошо работает. http://ssmaker.ru/9ac08e4a.png надеюсь я зделал все верно?)

Comment: @rodion, в `success` `$('#true_loadmore')` замените на  `$el`. В P.S. писал почему. Т.е.

     if(data) { 
          $el.text('Загрузить ещё').before(data);
          current_page++; 
          if (currentPage == maxPages) $el.remove(); 
     } else {
          $el.remove(); 
     }

Ибо при ` $('#true_loadmore')` каждый раз запускается поиск этого элемента.